# How to solve PyCharm error with docker "can't open file 'path/to/file.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"?

Tags: python, docker, pycharm, containers, jetbrains-ide

There is a server in the network, where our docker containers images are. I have build the image in the server, then on PyCharm I tried to follow the steps [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#config-docker), I could select the Docker settings, it shows the image that I have just created, let's say a image named 'teste1', I can see that all my libs were installed.

Until here everything is OK. But when I click to run any script from my project it shows the message:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/project/zoro/run_pipeline_and_persist.py'.

I have read [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52341979/pycharm-remote-interpreter-on-docker-remote-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory) about it, but didn't worked.

PyCharm version 2019.3

Comment: issue got fixed after pycharm restart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This setup (container on the remote machine) is not "natively" supported by PyCharm at the moment, unfortunately.

In the meantime, you can configure it to work with some extra clicks, please see the instruction in PyCharms' bug tracker (and vote for the ticket) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-33489

Basically you need to configure the deployment configuration alongside remote Docker interpreter and tweak path mappings.

Comment: I have followed that ticket twice and got the same error in both tries, same message "can't open file No such file or directory". I have restarted my computer and tried everything again and still same message.

Comment: It worked man, thank you. I tried once more and I changed the project mapping folder to one folder up and it worked.